# Getting errors when backing up and restoring postgres database from heroku to local

Tags: postgresql, powershell, heroku

I am creating a PowerShell script that will backup, download and restore my production database to my development database. It seems to be working but it is throwing errors during the process that I don't quite understand.

PowerShell script:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\database\backups'
cd $path

heroku pg:backups:capture -a card-companion
heroku pg:backups:download -a card-companion

pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U superuser -d dev latest.dump
```

Console Log:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\database\UpdateLocalDatabase.ps1
heroku : Starting backup of postgresql-defined-12858... done
At C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\database\UpdateLocalDatabase.ps1:8 char:1
+ heroku pg:backups:capture -a card-companion
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Starting backup...d-12858... done:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 

Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup will continue running.
Use heroku pg:backups:info to check progress.
Stop a running backup with heroku pg:backups:cancel.

Backing up DATABASE to b030... done
heroku : Getting backup from card-companion... fetching url of #30
At C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\database\UpdateLocalDatabase.ps1:9 char:1
+ heroku pg:backups:download -a card-companion
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Getting backup ...hing url of #30:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Getting backup from card-companion... done, #30
pg_restore : pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
At C:\Users\rossw\Documents\Projects\database\UpdateLocalDatabase.ps1:11 char:1
+ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U supe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (pg_restore: con...ase for restore:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
...
```

Comment: Looks like the `heroku` and `pg_restore` apps write status messages to `stderr`, which PowerShell then interprets as errors. Which version of PowerShell are you using? (`$PSVersionTable['PSVersion'] -as [string]`)

Comment: ah that makes sense. The version of PowerShell is `5.1.19041.1320`